# Arithmetic operation not working php

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a number is odd or not but arithmetic operator % always returns 0.

```
$gst=($gst)*(100); // here $gst value is 155 after multiplication with 100
if(($gst%2)== 1)
{
    $gst_receivable=(($gst-1)/2);
    $gst_expense=(($gst-1)/2)+1;
}
else
{
    $gst_receivable=($gst)/2;
    $gst_expense=($gst)/2;  
}
```

https://3v4l.org/8FQUf
But the above code always return **0** and runs the else part of the code.

Comment: Any non fractional number multiply by 100 is always a even number. Here your $gst become an even number $gst=($gst)*(100);

Comment: Previous value was 1.55 and after multiplying with 100 it become 155

Comment: echo ($gst%2)."\n"; returns 1; so your values are coming 77 & 78 resp.

Comment: You need to cast `$gst` to an integer before you use `%`. Like this: `if (((int)$gst % 2) == 1)` or `if ((intval($gst) % 2) == 1)`.

Comment: It return 0 not 1 that is the main issue.

Comment: Pretty sure $gst doesn't have the value you think it holds. Try with setting it to 1.55 directly, your code works great. https://3v4l.org/Pl6Vq

Comment: print the value of gst just before doing modulo operation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware there is no need for explicitly casting, php does that automatically.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de before claiming that `1.55 * 100` is `155`.

Comment: If you need to use the modulus for floats, then there is the [fmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function instead

Comment: @Gunnrryy: Yes, you're probably right.

Comment: if your value 1.55 then it should not be a problem. https://3v4l.org/JDufe But the logic of checking odd/even is not correct if $gst value can be 1.55 or anything

Comment: echo $gst returns 155

Comment: https://3v4l.org/8FQUf              Please check this link

Answer (score 0):

You need to `round()` the variable before doing `% 2` on it, because your float might still contain some rounding issues.

So change

```
if(($gst%2)== 1)
```

into

```
if(round($gst) % 2 == 1)
```